# How to get index of macro repetition single element

Tags: macros, rust

I need to get index of macro repetition element to write next code:

```
struct A {
    data: [i32; 3]
}

macro_rules! tst {
    ( $( $n:ident ),* ) => {
        impl A {
            $(
                fn $n(self) -> i32 {
                    self.data[?] // here I need the index
                }
            ),*
        }
    }
}
```

I know one way to do it: just tell user to write index by hands:

```
( $( $i:ident => $n:ident ),* )
```

But is there a more elegant way which does not require user's action?

Comment: What you are doing sounds very likely to be a bad idea. You should favour other designs where feasible; e.g. making a `struct A { one: i32, two: i32, three: i32 }`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan. In fact it relates to implementation of vectors like quaternions where every type has different length and requires different accessors. I thought it can simplify the work if I use one code for them all. Why do you think it is a bad idea?

Comment: I can’t grasp what you’re *actually* trying to achieve with this. Could you share a complete code example?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, well, by now it is just a concept, so no real code I can share exists. I can share it after completeon when (or if) I write it in the way I have asked.

Comment: Some solutions can be found in this RFC https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/28

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is to use recursion, like so:

```rust
struct A {
    data: [i32; 3]
}

macro_rules! tst {
    (@step $_idx:expr,) => {};

    (@step $idx:expr, $head:ident, $($tail:ident,)*) => {
        impl A {
            fn $head(&self) -> i32 {
                self.data[$idx]
            }
        }

        tst!(@step $idx + 1usize, $($tail,)*);
    };

    ($($n:ident),*) => {
        tst!(@step 0usize, $($n,)*);
    }
}

tst!(one, two, three);

fn main() {
    let a = A { data: [10, 20, 30] };
    println!("{:?}", (a.one(), a.two(), a.three()));
}
```

Note that I changed the method to take `&self` instead of `self`, since it made writing the example in the `main` function easier.  :)

Each step in the recursion just adds 1 to the index.  It is a good idea to use "typed" integer literals to avoid compilation slowdown due to lots and lots of integer inference.

Comment: Wow. Awesome. It just blew my mind. Rust still continues to surprise me :) Thank you very much, it is very interesting solution!

Comment: Wow. Back when I learned SML at uni I never expected that stuff to even be remotely useful. But here we are, writing SML lists in Rust.

Comment: What is the @step good for? Does the @ symbol have a special meaning in rust macros?